# How to change linespacing according to font size?

Tags: fonts, line-spacing

I'm preparing some labels for sending some suitcases.

How can I change the line spacing according to the font size?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\bfseries\pagenumbering{gobble}\centering\vfill
\begin{minipage}{.75\linewidth}
Mittente:

\begin{LARGE}
Sender Name\newline
Sender Address\newline
12345 City (XX)\newline
tel.\ 123456789
\end{LARGE}

Destinatario:

\begin{Huge}
Receiver Name\newline
Receiver Address\newline 
67890 Town (YY)\newline
tel.\ 01234567
\end{Huge}

\begin{LARGE}
Price \euro\ 11,11\newline 
Booking n. 12345
\end{LARGE}
\end{minipage}\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Leave a blank line before each \end{large} etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle David Purton found a duplicate (with that title, I would never have found it).

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I guess that is partly why I asked [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/how-similar-should-two-questions-be-to-qualify-as-a-duplicates). But in this case, I felt like your question is more likely to be how people search when they have a problem, but the other question contains exactly the right explanation.

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, exactly! I hope my question won't be deleted, I think my title could be useful.

Comment: I don't think duplicates get deleted unless you delete them, so should be all good